# Ubuntu 12.04 no desktop, only terminal

Tags: unity, gnome, command-line, cinnamon

I installed cinnamon and uninstall unity using a terminal command I found on the web, but I skipped some steps on removing unity thinking it was not important. Now, when I turn on my laptop it will only boot to terminal, it doesn't go to to log in screen to log in to cinnamon desktop or gnome classic. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried starting the login manager manually? Try `sudo service lightdm start`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try to repair the display manager

1. start lightdm service, it is maybe stopped

   ```
   sudo service lightdm start
   ```
2. reconfigure, In case the first option doesn't work

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
   ```
3. reinstall. The worst case

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
   ```

I suggest you to install Gnome. It's my preferred Desktop Environment

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: For configuration problems (rather than corrupted files), it is usually sufficient to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Since `sudo service lightdm start` worked (see comments on the question), this would most likely have been sufficient. But it is important to know about `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` too, as that will fix corrupted files in `lightdm`.

Answer (score 0):

Tou need a display manager. Try `xinit` or `startx` commands. If your gui starts, you need to install a *display manager*, which lets you log into a gui session. Because you uninstalled Unity, you probably removed `lightdm`, the default display manager in Ubuntu. So you can either install `gdm` or `lightdm`. I suggest gdm, because you have Cinnamon installed:

`sudo apt-get install <your choice here>`

If your gui didn't start after `xinit` or `startx`, you need to install your preferred gui environment again. I haven't used cinnamon before, so I would direct you to http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/09/20/install-cinnamon-1-6-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/ .